# How to view the returned string by the server in the console before JSON parsing it?

Tags: android, json

I am trying connect my android app to localhost and fetch data in form of JSON string. 
The url **http://mysite.dev/controller/read/format/json** to fetch JSON data successfully returns :

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "products": [
        {
            "annonce_id": 462,
            "accountType": "Particulier"                
        }
    ]
}
```

**ANDROID CODE:**

```
// Building parameters
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

try {

   // getting JSON string from URL
   JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);              
   Log.d("Status", json.toString());

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", e.toString());
}
```

**Error message the from console:** 
[image]

Based on the error message from console, I have been wondering where the **HTML** is coming from. Is there any way to view in the console the actual string returned by the server before being JSON parsed? This will help me know exactly what is being returned.

N.B: I a new at Android, and just following this tutorial: **http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/**
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the function makeHttpRequest in your code. There look for the line where you actually get response from the server and then Log.d for printing log in console before it parses it.

Answer (score 0):

@Sharj Sorry I can't comment as the response I got from the server is quite long. For some reason, due my application is connecting to my localhost, it couldn't recognise the domain as a valid one. I have uploaded everything online. Thanks.

```
07-11 18:41:45.233: I/global(26861): Loaded time zone names for en_US in 14773ms.
07-11 18:41:45.343: W/ResponseProcessCookies(26861): Cookie rejected: "BasicClientCookie[version=0,name=OUS,domain=.opendns.com,path=/,expiry=Thu Jan 01 00:00:01 GMT+00:00 1970]". Illegal domain attribute "opendns.com". Domain of origin: "www.website-unavailable.com"
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861): <html>
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):     <head>
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):         <title>  </title>
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):         <script type="text/javascript">
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):             function bredir(a, b, c, d, e, ldr, ifc) {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 var h, i, j;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 var f = 0;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 var g = 0;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 var k = false;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 var l = false;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 var m = [
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [300, 250, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [250, 250, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [240, 400, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [336, 280, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [180, 150, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [468, 60, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [234, 60, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [88, 31, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [120, 90, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [120, 60, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [120, 240, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [125, 125, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [728, 90, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [160, 600, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [120, 600, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [300, 600, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [300, 125, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [530, 300, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [190, 200, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [470, 250, false],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [720, 300, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [500, 350, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [550, 480, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     //YouTube:
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [560, 315, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [640, 360, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [853, 480, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [1280, 720, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     //Vimeo:
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [400, 300, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [500, 281, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     //Hulu:
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [480, 270, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [512, 288, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     //metacafe:
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [440, 248, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [460, 284, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [540, 304, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [600, 338, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     //Other dimensions (metacafe, myspace video, yahoo video, break.com, ustream, vevo, justin.tv, etc):
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [210, 120, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [400, 300, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [425, 350, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [425, 360, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [435, 251, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [435, 271, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [500, 300, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [525, 295, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [575, 324, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [620, 389, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [624, 351, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [630, 381, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [640, 385, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [650, 368, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [1000, 562, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [1000, 563, true],
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     [1000, 564, true]
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 ];
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 if (typeof window.innerHeight == "number") {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     g = window.innerHeight;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     f = window.innerWidth;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 } else if (typeof document.body.offsetHeight == "number") {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     g = document.body.offsetHeight;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     f = document.body.offsetWidth;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 }
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 for (var n = 0; n < m.length; n++) {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     j = m[n];
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     h = Math.abs(f - j[0]);
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     i = Math.abs(g - j[1]);
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     if (top != self) {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                         ifc = 1;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     } else {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                         ifc = 0;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     };
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     if (h <= 2 && i <= 2) {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                         k = true;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                         l = j[2]
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     }
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 }
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 if(f === 0 && g === 0){
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     return;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 }
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 if ((a != "www.facebook.com" && a != "platform.twitter.com") && (k || f < 100 && f !== 0 || g < 100 && g !== 0)) {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     if (l && self == parent) {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                         return;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     }
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     return "/b" + "anner.php?w=" + f + "&h=" + g + "&d=" + a + "&url=" + b + "&ref=" + c + "&view=" + d
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                 } else if ((a == "www.facebook.com" || a == "platform.twitter.com") && (f >= 250 && g >= 60) && (k || f < 100 && f !== 0 || g < 100 && g !== 0)) {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                     if (l && self == parent) {
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):                         return;
07-11 18:41:46.063: D/json(26861):
```